# How to print a 2 pages in portrait mode on single page which is also in portrait mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, pdf, printing

I have a PDF of the size w=105mm and h=297mm (ie A4 split vertically)
Now I wanted to print this PDF to  generate another PDF which will have two pages from original PDF placed vertically side-by-side in an A4 sheet which also should be in portrait mode.

I have tried various settings via the Linux Mint system printer but it always either rotates the pages of input file or rotates the page to landscape mode in the output file. I've also tried Google Chrome's print PDF feature but that too doesn't support multiple portrait pages in a portrait output page.

*Is there any command-line tool in Linux/Ubuntu that can achieve what I'm trying?*

Here is a sample file for trail (Just in case): [PDF File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1efuOk7oYDvzyGTgvkgonG9Ng0glqKjTJ)

Comment: Not exactly the same requirements but maybe a base for your solution: https://superuser.com/questions/96058/pdf-manipulation-2-up-page-layout

Answer (score 3):

The [pdfjam](https://github.com/DavidFirth/pdfjam) utility is the de facto standard for this kind of manipulation. A `pdfnup` wrapper may be available but it was recently removed from pdfjam. It is [available in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pdfnup&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any) in the package [texlive-extra-utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/texlive-extra-utils).

If I understand your requirements correctly, it's very simple:

```
pdfjam --nup 2x1 HalfA4V.pdf -o a4.pdf
```

Comment: How do I install pdfjam on Linux Mint? Followed the steps on https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/pdfjam but apt-get says package not found. :(     Prerequisites are too many and large...

Comment: @YourPalNurav The Ubuntu package name is not `pdfjam`, it's `texlive-extra-utils`. See https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1525 for generic instructions on installing Ubuntu packages on Mint.

Comment: will `texlive-extra-utils` install working pdfjam or will I have to install the complete texlive or latex package?

Comment: @YourPalNurav You need to install this package. The dependencies (mostly on other texlive packages) will be installed automatically.